# dismissViewControllerAnimated causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS 7.1 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

`ViewControllerA` opens `ViewControllerB` using a modal segue.

`ViewControllerA`:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ModalSegue is defined in the storyboard to point to ViewControllerB
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ModalSegue" sender:self];
}
```

`ViewControllerB`:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // Causes crash
}
```

In iOS 7.1, this causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. If Zombie Objects is turned on it throws the exception:

`*** -[ViewControllerB respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12ed7e170`

In iOS 7.0, this works as expected.

Any ideas?

EDIT: As per LeoNatan's request, here's the stack trace of the `dealloc` method in `ViewControllerB`:

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: Are you using ARC? From the message you can see that your ViewControlllerB instance has been over-released.

Comment: Instruments can help you track this down using the Allocations instrument.

Comment: Implement the `dealloc` method for `ViewControllerB` and set a breakpoint there. See who has released your view controller. Post the stack trace here.

Comment: @LeoNatan question has been edited with stack trace.

Comment: @nielsbot yes, I'm using ARC. I'll try Instruments.

Comment: @DylanHand `redacted` :-) You can see a more complete stack trace on the left Xcode pane.

Comment: @LeoNatan is there an easy way to copy that without transcribing it by hand?

Comment: Using `Grab` app in OS X. Make sure to scroll the verboseness to maximum (slider all the way to the right).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49703/discussion-between-dylan-hand-and-leo-natan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in chat, the problem is a picker view having a longer lifespan than its view controller, causing it to attempt sending a message to its delegate.

The solution is to set the delegate and data source of the picker view to `nil` in the `dealloc` method.

With iOS 7 and above, it is considered good practice to set delegates and data sources to `nil`, because views have a longer lifespan than their view controllers and try to access their delegates after these have been released.

Comment: thanks for this, it's been rather helpful! Would you have a link to some resource, possibly one of Apple's, confirming your good-practice-suggestion?

Comment: @epologee Not sure if I can find something concrete. The problem is, the view controller is released earlier than its view hierarchy. It's because Apple moves the view hierarchy to another view for the animation, so it is retained outside of the controller.